# Use of the term “entire “ for real valued functions

Tags: complex-analysis

> If $f=u+iv$ is an entire function can we say that $u$ and $v$ are also entire? Can we apply Liouville’s theorem separately to $u$, $v$ if they are bounded?

I know the term “entire “ applies to complex valued functions but real valued functions can also be considered as complex valued with zero imaginary part. But is there anything wrong with using it with real valued functions?

Comment: No, entire functions are holomorphic. But the only real-valued holomorphic functions on $\Bbb C$ are constant.

Comment: You can say that $u$ and $v$ are harmonic functions.

Comment: It is true that if $u$ or $v$ is bounded  and $u+iv$ is analytic then it is a constant. You can prove this by applying Liouville's Theorem to $e^{u+iv}$ and $e^{-iu+v}$.